# restricting rows on solr subquery/join

Tags: join, solr, subquery

I want to implement a search on solr that takes the 500 bestselling products, and then does a search/filter on those 500 products only

In SQL, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT TOP 500 ProductID FROM Product ORDER BY Sales DESC)
AND Manufacturer = 'Apple'
```

I know I can do join/subqueries in solr, but I can't seem to work out how to sort and limit the rows of these subqueries before they are fed into the main query.

Is this possible in solr?

Answer (score 0):

You probably wont need any Joins or Subqueries.
You would index the Products with the Sales information.

You just need to execute a Solr Query :-

```
q=manufacturer:apple&sort=sales desc&limit=500
```

OR

```
fq=manufacturer:apple&sort=sales desc&limit=500
```

This would search the manufacture field for apple, return the result set ordered by sales in the descending order and limit the rows to 500.
Fetching 500 would probably not be a good idea and you can always do pagination with rows and limit.
The limit of showing only 500 results can be handled at client side.

Comment: Yes - I could do that of course. But - I'm actually looking for the top 500 products, and THEN to filter it, so the resulting list may only be say, 50 for instance, depending on the filters I choose.

Comment: Nope Solr does not have a feature like this. You can modify the Source code to limit the number of results though.